Hot Reload not working after upgrading xamarin.form 4.6 to 5.0.0.2662
I have upgraded xamarin.form version 4.6 to 5.0.0.2662. I am using VS 2022
I enable hot reload in vs, shown in image
When I make any changes.
In output window of (Xamarin hot reload) showing statement that
[14:15:31]  XAML Hot Reload Connected and Ready.
[14:17:19]  (app.Android) Xaml Changed for 'Pages/LoginPage.xaml' in '', sending to app...
[14:17:20]  Successfully reloaded: ReloadChange in Pages/LoginPage.xaml
But changes are not updating on mobile or emulator UI.
Please share guidance.



I would recommend you repair your VS, If this still does not work you won't be able to do anything since Xamarin is now out of support

But it is working when creating new xamarin project

Does your page have control templates?
